# setup for an xll on a computer where visual is not installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, dependencies, xll

I developped an xll with visual studio 2010 and excel 2010. it works fine on excel on the computer where visual is installed. But now, i'm trying to use my xll in a computer where visual is not installed, so i want to create a setup.

In fact, i tried to execute my xll on a windows where nothing is installed (only excel 2010) : it's not working. So i have installed "visual 2010 C++ redistribuable package" in X64 and X86. After i tried again to execute my xll in excel and it's not working again.

**Edit** : I used "depends.exe" on my two xll. On the xll which is not working, the C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.DLL has a red picture on the left but the xll which is working has not this dll on error :

[image: error with depends.exe]

So my question is what the xll need in addtion to the C++ package to be execute on a computer without visual ?

Or do you have a simply method to create a setup for an xll (i have created a setup with visual and it's not working so maybe there is an other method...).

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  Any error messages?

Comment: on the computer where visual is not installed : after i put my xll on EXCEl, i try to put on a cell "=Myfunc", there are no list of function who match it. I put the same XLL on the computer where visual is installed and where it works : when i put "=Myfunc" i have a list of function who correspond to the function of my XLL

Comment: If you are using the shell functions in SHLWAPI.DLL you might be linking to features which are not available on the target operating system. If you are compiling against the newest version of the Windows SDK, but running on Windows XP, you'd get this behaviour. More on dealing with different versions of the shell libraries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776779(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also you can attach your debugger to the Excel process, then load the add-in and inspect the debugger output. Failure to load some .dll will show in the debugger output. Else start with a simpler add-in, then add your features to see at what point it breaks.

Comment: I can't do it on the computer where my XLL is not working because visual 2010 is not installed. If I install visual, my XLL will work, but i want to use it without installing visual.

Comment: Try with a simple .xll that just registers one function.

Comment: OK it's done : With a simple XLL which with one function (a + b), it's working on the computer where visual is installed, but it's not working on the computer where visual is not installed but where the  C/C++ runtime for the release version of VS 2010 is installed.... so same result as my first XLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

first you need to install the redistributable of you development environment (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/fr-fr/details.aspx?FamilyID=c68ccbb6-75ef-4c9d-a326-879eab4fcdf8) for VS2010 with Service Pack 1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) for VS.

In a second time you need to install Visual Studio 2010 tools for Office Runtime (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/fr-fr/details.aspx?familyid=06c32242-2289-4471-93aa-ce96aa5cbc36)

Answer (score 1):

There are separate redistributions of the C/C++ runtime for the release version of VS 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and VS 2010 with Service Pack 1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328), and you need to install the one matching your development environment.

An alternative would be to change to static linking of the C/C++ runtime for your add-in.

[image: Setting the Runtime Library]

Also check that your Excel macro security is not set to 'high' or a setting that disables add-ins.

Comment: "An alternative would be to change to static linking of the C/C++ runtime for your add-in" How can you do this ?

Comment: i tried with the C/C++ runtime for the release version of VS2010 with SP1 (who is the same as my development environment) and set my Excel macro security to 'none security' and it's not working again. Maybe i have some new elements (in the edit part of my question) which can help us

Comment: Added a picture of the static linking. But this is not your problem if you have tried with the right C/C++ runtime installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://xll.codeplex.com to create xll's and you won't have to worry about this.